# Way to read/write exported kernel symbols from user land

Tags: linux-kernel

Is there a way to read or write a kernel variable which is exported with EXPORT_SYMBOL macro ?

Thanks

Comment: User space application cannot access to the kernel's variables, whenever they are exported or not. Otherwise, I don't understand your question.

Comment: So we need to write a kernel module in order to access kernel variables ?

Comment: Yes, only kernel parts - kernel core or its modules - may access to kernel variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing variable in kernel-space from user-level space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202160/accessing-variable-in-kernel-space-from-user-level-space)